# Catch specific element from for loop using jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a for loop created with jinja2 on my html, showing a list of users in my sqlite database:

```
        {% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% if user.admin == True: %}
                        <a href="{{ url_for('changePermission' }}"> Admin Icon </a>
                    {% else: %}
                        <a href="{{ url_for('changePermission' }}"> Not Admin Icon </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

I would like to know how can I pick the specific user from the line the link is clicked?
I tried to catch it through url_for:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('changePermission', user=user") }}"> Admin Icon </a>
```

But I got this message on terminal:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'

I don't know what is the more appropriated way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be because of a syntax error rather than anything to do with your loops. You seem to have an extra double quote in your `url_for` arguments: `user=user"` should be `user=user`. This extra quotation mark has the undesired effect of closing the value of the `href` attribute which also starts with a double quote, leaving the closing brackets and braces outside of the attribute. Your `<a>` tag should look like this:

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('changePermission', user=user) }}">Admin Icon</a>
```

It is generally considered best practice to use double quotes in HTML attribute values, so use single quotes when inserting strings with Jinja for arguments.